# How to auto-close xml tags in truncated file?

Tags: python, xml, notepad++

I receive an email when a system in my company generates an error. This email contains XML all crammed onto a single line.

I wrote a notepad++ Python script that parses out everything except XML and pretty prints it. Unfortunately some of the emails contain too much XML data and it gets truncated. In general, the truncated data isn't that important to me. I would like to be able to just auto-close any open tags so that my Python script works. It doesn't need to be smart or correct, it just needs to make the xml well-enough formed that the script runs. Is there a way to do this?

I am open to Python scripts, online apps, downloadable apps, etc.

- I realize that the right solution is to get the non-truncated xml, but pulling the right lever to get things done will be far more work than just dealing with it.

Comment: Duplicate of [Close all opened xml tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1644994/close-all-opened-xml-tags?rq=1)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
>>> import bs4
>>> s= bs4.BeautifulSoup("<asd><xyz>asd</xyz>")
>>> s
<html><head></head><body><asd><xyz>asd</xyz></asd></body></html>
>>
>>> s.body.contents[0]
<asd><xyz>asd</xyz></asd>
```

Notice that it closed the "asd" tag automagically"

To create a notepad++ script to handle this,

- [download the tarball](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/download/) and extract the files
- Copy the **bs4** directory to your PythonScript/scripts folder.
- In notepad++ add the following code to your python script

```
#import Beautiful Soup
import bs4
#get text in document
text = editor.getText()
#soupify it to fix XML
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(text)
#convert soup object to string again
text = str(soup)
#clear editor and replace bad xml with fixed xml
editor.clearAll()
editor.addText(text)
#change language to xml
notepad.menuCommand( MENUCOMMAND.LANG_XML )
#soup has its own prettify, but I like the XML tools version better
notepad.runMenuCommand('XML Tools', 'Pretty print (XML only - with line breaks)', 1)
```

Comment: XML and HTML are not the same - depending on the data being processed, not specifying the XML parser might lead to the data being incorrectly interpreted (as well as adding the cruft shown in your example).

Answer (score 3):

If you have [BeautifulSoup and lxml](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parsing-xml) installed, it's straightforward:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("""
... <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
... <a>
...   <b>foo</b>
...   <c>bar</""", "xml")
>>> soup
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<a>
<b>foo</b>
<c>bar</c></a>
```

Note the second `"xml"` argument to the constructor to avoid the XML being interpreted as HTML.